# How to add pointing system for player and computer. First to have 3 points will win

Tags: python, random

My problem with my program is that it does not retain the score of the computer and the player. I know that my problem is that the loop will declare it again as 0. Is there any solution for this? I am just learning Python so I cannot process it deeply.

```py
import random
 
print("WELCOME TO THE GUESSING GAME!")
 
name = input("Please enter your name: ")

def main():
    
    first = int(input("Enter a starting number: "))
 
    second = int(input("Enter an ending number: "))
 
    chances = 3
 
    x = random.randint(first, second)
    print("You've only ", 
           chances,
          " chances to guess the secret number.\n")
 
    tries = 0
    player = 0
    computer= 0
 
    while tries < chances:
        tries += 1
 
        guess = int(input("Guess a number: "))
 
        if x > guess:
            print("Sorry " + name + " you guessed too small.")
          
            
        if x < guess:
            print("Sorry " + name + " you guessed too high.")
 
    if x == guess:
            player += 1
            print("The player has" , player, "points")  
            print("Congratulations " + name + " you guessed it")
    
    if computer == 3:
        print("The Computer won. Better luck next time,", name)
        break
    
    if player == 3:
        print("The Player won! Congrats", name)
        break
               
    else:
        computer += 1
        print("The computer has" , computer, "points")
        print("\nThe secret number is", x)
        print("\t\nGAME OVER!")
 
    restart=input("Ready for the next round? Type yes or no:").lower()
    if restart == "yes":
        print("\n\tGood luck" , name)
        main()
    else:
        print("\n\tThank you for playing", name)
        exit()
 
main()
```

Comment: The problem is that you call the `main()` function inside of your `if` statement. I would remove that call and then put everything at the top of the function inside of the while loop.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I just learned that you can use global variables to exclude it in the function. I really appreciate all of your amswers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0):

Now it works:

```
import random
 
print("WELCOME TO THE GUESSING GAME!")
 
name = input("Please enter your name: ")

def main():
    
    while True:
        first = int(input("Enter a starting number: "))
        second = int(input("Enter an ending number: "))
        if second < first:
            print("Die zweite Zahl muss größer sein\n")
            continue
        elif first == 0 or second == 0:
            print("Die Grenzen dürfen nicht null sein\n")
            continue
        else:
            break

 
    chances = 3
 
    x = random.randint(first, second)
    print("You've only ", 
           chances,
          " chances to guess the secret number.\n")
 
    tries = 0
    player = 0
    computer= 0
 
    while tries < chances:
        tries += 1
 
        guess = int(input("Guess a number: "))
 
        if x > guess:
            print("Sorry " + name + " you guessed too small.")
                    
        elif x < guess: 
            print("Sorry " + name + " you guessed too high.")
 
        elif x == guess:  
                player += 1
                print("The player has" , player, "points")  
                print("Congratulations " + name + " you guessed it")
                break
               
        if player == 3:
            print("The Player won! Congrats", name)
            break
                
        else:
            computer += 1
            print("The computer has" , computer, "points")
            
        if computer == 3:
            print("The Computer won. Better luck next time,", name)
            print("\t\nGAME OVER!") 
            print("\nThe secret number is", x) 

            restart=input("Ready for the next round? Type yes or no:").lower()

            if restart == "yes":
                print("\n\tGood luck" , name)
                main()
            else:
                print("\n\tThank you for playing", name)
                exit()
        
    
main()
```

In the end you got a little confused with your indentations I think.
If there are more trouble, let me know.

Comment: And as mentioned, put your program into a `while loop` to avoid calling the main function recursively in an if statement.

Comment: this code crashes if any one of the input number is a zero.

Comment: Thanks for the note, I have fixed it.